# Is there a standard parameter in Visual Studio for logged in users?

Tags: t-sql, visual-studio-2008

I’m using Visual Studio 2008 (R2) to create reports that use T-SQL procedures. Is there a way to define a standard parameter that looks which user is logged in to the system and returns the name or anything else of that user as a parameter back?

Comment: What do you mean by "using Visual Studio"? Do you mean you're using the SQL Explorer to execute the command? Or are you running the application via the debugger that executes the command?

Comment: Do you mean something like [`User_Name()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188014.aspx) and associated functions? Or do you want everyone currently connected, e.g. [`sys.dm_exec_connections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181509.aspx)?

Comment: That is the software that I’m using “SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio”, there I can create reports that use procedures and the parameters from those procedures. 
I think that the option “everybody currently connected” is what I’m looking for. When some wants to use the report on his computer (one person per computer) then the parameter will return the user’s “login name”.